# What is causing this deformation while using Boolean Union on all objects?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing, distort

So I want to prepare my 3d model for printing but when I try to merge it with boolean it all gets pretty messy. I'm beginner and I really don't know how to fix this problem. Here are some images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/da6hz.png

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: in the modifier stack, things have to be in the correct order, check the stack by moving things up and down.